# Swift Eureka Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, uistoryboard, eureka-forms

sorry bit a noob question. I'm having a look at the Eureka Form framework and have this question. Should I expect to see anything in the Storyboard, i.e. if I have a view controller on the storyboard and makes its class the same as the Eureka class, should I see the coded rows on the storyboard.

If I should, and I'm not, is there anything else I need to do?

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka makes everything through code so you wont be able to see anything in the Storyboard :(. You have to execute your code to see the forms.

Best,

Enrique